# Android Studio suddenly does not respond

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

When I try opening the Android Studios, it just bounces once on my dock (app bar on the bottom of a mac) and nothing happens. Before it used to work fine, I made a couple of projects, but since I haven't opened in a few weeks and I guess it doesn't work anymore.

When I redownload it, it bounces multiple times, but still doesn't respond. I looked everywhere on Stack overflow but I can't find anything helpful. Plz help!!

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me also. For the latest version I use terminal to open Android Studio. Open terminal and type `android-studio` and press Enter.
I use Manjaro KDE. I hope this will work as same as mine.